# update and add more new string fields to object in mongodb by using pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to understand how to add more strings fields inside an existing object in this case "button" by using pymongo with flask after getting data from post request?
the db looks like this:
[the db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sLS8.png)

and the python code is somthing like :

```
mydb=mongo["database"]
web_data=mydb["web_data"]
group_data=mydb["group_data"]
group={
    "setting_tab": request.form.get("form"),
    "name": request.form.get("name")
}
send_group_data_newbutton = {
    "$set": {
        "button": { request.form.get("button_id"):"test" }
    }
}
group_data.update_one(group, send_group_data_newbutton, upsert=False)
```

the code works fine but the problem is that instead of adding new lines in the db it overwrite the existent field

Comment: Let the body of POST request is `form=forms&name=BOB` and filter `group` matches only one object you give us as an example. As for me, it's not clear what do you want to get in the end? How object should be modified? What is `group_data`? Collection? There is `update_one` https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update_one. Or `update_many`. `update` is deprecated. Could you edit your question to include additional details?

Comment: I change it now this is ok?

Comment: Very nice. But the most important - what object should be look like after modifications, you described it in words, but much more understandable it will be "object I have" (present) -> "object I wanna get" (missing). So your object has subobject `button` with keys `off` and `new button` and you want to set new key with name taken from `request.form.get('button_id')` with value `'test'` keeping all existing ones. Right?

Comment: Also write, please, what's wrong with code you posted? Have you executed it?

Comment: Try a dotted path for `$set`, https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#behavior. Like `{'$set': {'button.{}'.format(request.form.get('button_id'): 'test'}}`. Not able to run it myself soon and be sure.

Comment: yes, its work fine thank you so much mrEvgenX